# Facebook pictures of comments, comment

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, laravel-5

I need to get the picture of the replies to comments i've used this so far to get the pictures of the first level comments it looks like this.

```
$reso = $this->getFB()->get("$id/comments?fields=likes,message,comments,from{
    likes,comments,name,picture
}", $pageToken);
```

This returns the picture with no problems but only for the first level of comments i have no idea how to get the picture for the replies to a comment?

**Current Array Returned**

```
array:2 [▼
  "data" => array:13 [▼
    0 => array:4 [▼
      "message" => "OOh nice!"
      "from" => array:4 [▼
        "likes" => array:2 [▶]
        "name" => "McKenzie Flavius"
        "picture" => array:1 [▶]
        "id" => "186894038315206"
      ]
      "id" => "1687724354827858_1687724421494518"
      "comments" => array:2 [▼
        "data" => array:1 [▼
          0 => array:2 [▼
            "message" => "replied ooh nice"
            "id" => "1687724354827858_1687769078156719" //I need to get picture in this array here!
          ]
        ]
        "paging" => array:1 [▶]
      ]
    ]
    1 => array:4 [▶]
    2 => array:4 [▶]
    3 => array:4 [▶]
    4 => array:4 [▶]
    5 => array:3 [▶]
    6 => array:4 [▶]
    7 => array:4 [▶]
    8 => array:4 [▶]
    9 => array:4 [▶]
    10 => array:4 [▶]
    11 => array:4 [▶]
    12 => array:4 [▶]
  ]
  "paging" => array:1 [▶]
]
```

As always all help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, so when passing the following argument as part of the url to facebook.

```
COMMENT-ID/comments?fields=likes,message,comments,$accessToken;
```

I needed to use this `{'Sub-Field Info Here'}` with the argument to get the subfields that i want, so to get the pictures from the comments i did the following:

```
COMMENT-ID/comments?fields=likes,message,comments{from{picture,name}}, $accessToken;
```

Notice I put the `{from{picture,name}}` immediately besides the `comments` argument that has been passed this means that the data pulled back will be related to the comments field. So ultimately here i have retrieved the 'picture' and the 'name' From the comments giving me something like the following:

```
"comments" => "from"[
     "picture" => "PICTURE-LINK",
     "name"    => "NAME"
]
```

Comment: Could add more info, please?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Is that better..?

Comment: This looks awesome. Voted up. Yours was said as low quality post. So instead of downvoting, I really wanna approach you and tell you that if you could add more info it would sound better and you did it. Great! *Now shut up and take my votes!* `:P`